# Are you applying to other places as well?

Tags: interviewing, job-search

I'm not entirely satisfied with my current employer, but for some reasons not in the position to search actively. I still apply to some interesting positions from time to time and get invited to the interviews.

During the interview we normally discus why I want to switch and the hiring manager asks if I'm looking for other places as well. I usually respond that I'm not out looking actively and do not feel any urgency in switching places, but I really like what this very company is doing and thinking that I would want to join bla-bla-bla.

How is it from the employer's view? Should I stick to the answer or should I say that there are other offers as well, implying they should make heir mind faster?

Comment: https://www.thebalance.com/why-are-you-leaving-your-job-2061203

Comment: Your answer tells me you're not interested so I wouldn't want to hire you. Speak confidently, "I am looking to switch jobs and your place seems like the kind of place I want to work at because of X." Don't add stuff like, "maybe" or "just looking" or whatever that "blah blah" is.